# Auto Layout UILabels

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, ios6, autolayout

I have three `UILabels` in my custom `UITableViewCell`.
It might be that some `UILabels` will be empty (`label.text == @""`)

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"EventCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


        NSString *key = [[keysArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] description];

        UILabel *nameLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
        namelabel.text = @"Label 1";

        UILabel *locationLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
        location.text = @"Label 2";

        UILabel *timeLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:102];
        timeLabel.text = @"";

        return cell;
}
```

How can I centre all non-empty `UILabels` vertically in the cell using auto-layout?

**This is how it looks with three labels**

[image: This is how it looks with three labels:]

**How it looks when one of `UILables` is empty**

[image: How it looks when one of <code>UILables</code> is empty]

**And this is how I want it to look:**

[image: And this is how I want it to look:]

Comment: Are you building the cell in code or in interface builder? Why does it matter if the labels are empty or not?

Comment: In IB. I want my labels be centered in container. It is not difficult to make, but when one of labels is empty then I get a gap between two other labels which doesn't look nice

Comment: This might be very hard, because an empty UILabel maybe doesn't claim width but certainly height, so you may have to write some code along the lines of 'of one of the labels is empty, remove that label'.

Comment: Well, I can call -removeFromSuperview or just make empty label be nil.  How can I do the rest? What constraints should I use to align my other  labels?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is tricky to achieve, but a simple shortcut may be to have a single label instead, with three lines of text, constrained to fill the whole height of the cell. The label will then auto-center its contents vertically.

You'd have three string properties on the cell instead of three labels, and your setters would build the final string (using `\n` for new lines) and set the label's text.

If each line of text has different styling, no problem, as you can use attributed strings.

Comment: Very nice approach! Will do like you suggest. And will use attributed strings because my labels have different styling! Thank you!

Comment: Actually I was thinking someone will suggest to add/modify constraints programmatically, but this solution is much simpler!

Comment: Modifying the constraints is possible, but certainly harder than doing it this way. It may also affect your scrolling performance as you'd be either adding/removing subviews or changing layout as each cell comes on screen, both of which are expensive operations.